# how to make one to many relationship in my comment table

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel

I've put this code in my articles migration:

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('author');
    $table->longText('description');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('tags');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

end then i use this code in my comment migration file :

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedInteger('article_id');
    $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('user_id');
    $table->string('user_name'); 
    $table->longtext('teks');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and when i try to make migration with php artisan, my terminal gives error message is :

**("SQLSTATE[HY000]:
General error: 1005 Can't create table
`projek_akhir_laravel`.`comments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In migrations, `$this->id();` generate a `unsignedBigInteger` field.

So your field which will contain your foreign key needs to have the same format :

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
    ....
}
```

You can use this helper for foreigns :

```
$table->foreignId('article_id'); // generate an unsigned big integer field
```